# Ionic App Showing default icon when installing

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am facing an issue in the Ionic App icon, how I can fix it? please see images

[image: Waiting Image]

[image: After 1 second Waiting Image]

---

Ionic Information

Ionic:

Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.9 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.4.2
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.9
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.3.9
   @angular/cli                  : 7.3.9
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.5.1

Capacitor:

Capacitor CLI   : 1.1.0
   @capacitor/core : 1.1.0

Cordova:

Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : ios 5.1.1
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.0.1, (and 7 other plugins)

Utility:

cordova-res : 0.8.1 
   native-run  : not installed

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/Users/iosdev/Library/Android/sdk)
   ios-deploy        : 2.0.0
   ios-sim           : 8.0.2
   NodeJS            : v10.15.3 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.10.3
   OS                : macOS Mojave
   Xcode             : Xcode 10.2.1 Build version 10E1001

Comment: Have you created resources correctly?

Comment: @Sampath Yes resources showing correctly no default icon exist in code but still showing for 1 seconds when i try to install

Answer (score 0):

u can try these steps, (i solved mine like this only) 
1. `npm remove cordova-res`
2. `npm install cordova-res`
and then replace those default icon with your custom one once again and 
 run `ionic cordova resources`  that will generate your custom icon and it should be shown.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug, its IOS default functionality, Try with lots of top applications from the App store showing the same.